# How to make a table view which is not the full width of the screen?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

For some strange reason, UITableView resizes my cells to 320 width no matter how I set the frame for the UITableView object.

Even if I go in later and resize the cell back to 250, UITableView seems to resize it again to 320 some time.

Is there some property or method that must be set / called additionally to get that right?

However, I can add my contents in a way that it looks like 250 width, but my whole layouting code is a big mess since I can't rely on the cell frame width which is "wrong". Also it seems like a big waste of memory since the bitmaps in the layer trees are nonsenseless 320 width instead of 250, even though the frame of the UITableView is not 320 width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 220.0, 385.0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```