# How do you change the width of a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iPhone development, coming from a web application development background and I'm working on my first project. I chose to create a Navigation based project, since after reading it seemed to be the easiest way to get what I'm after. How do you change the width of the UITableView? Eventually, I'd like to have a top bar, UITableView, and bottom bar be 304px wide. I've tried the following in my RootViewController's viewDidLoad method, but I'm doing it wrong:

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.size.width = 200;
self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `tableViewFrame.size.bounds.width` Note the `bounds`.

Comment: Tried that, I get an error about bounds not being a member of CGSize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the width of the tableViewCell.. go to cellForRowAtIndexPath, and assign it there.

You could also do -

```
CGFloat tableBorderLeft = 1;
CGFloat tableBorderRight = 1;

CGRect tableRect = self.view.frame;
tableRect.origin.x += tableBorderLeft; // make the table begin a few pixels right from its origin
tableRect.size.width -= tableBorderLeft + tableBorderRight; // reduce the width of the table
tableView.frame = tableRect;
```

For changing the size of header

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 150.0;  //Give a value
}
```

For changing size of footer

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 150.0;//Give a value
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the former may be what I'm after. If I want to change the width of the top and bottom bar as well UITableViewCells, do I just change the width of the entire view instead of each control at that point?

Comment: Well, this is a very simple way to set the width for a tableView.  If you want to change the height of header or footer, you will have to implement methods as I have posted above (extra code)

Comment: I tried your first advice; setting the UITableViewCell width, but couldn't get anything working. So I've moved onto your example code, which I placed under [super viewDidLoad], but the table is still the width of the screen (screenshot: http://cl.ly/7Um8).

Comment: Do not use it in viewDidLoad. Use it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Looks the same there, though, after re-building, screenshot: http://cl.ly/7VW3

Comment: Hm, I just tested it in mine. Works fine !! Check it. http://www.cl.ly/140I1P0j1K1m2k0l113K

Comment: Bummer, can't imagine what could be different. I'll just keep sniffing around, thanks for the help.

Comment: Lol. Even if you just copy paste the first few lines, it should work !! No clue why your screen is not responding.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I haven't yet populated the cell with anything.

Comment: Did you remove all that you typed in your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Yep. Also copied and pasted your example directly into my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: How about in Interface Builder; is there any way to drag the UITableView out to whatever size I want and have the app abide by that exact size? As it stands, even if I make the UITableView 300x100 in IB, it covers the whole screen at runtime.

Comment: Alright man. got it. Just initialize the array with an object. It will work.

Comment: Also check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731312/how-to-make-a-table-view-which-is-not-the-full-width-of-the-screen

Comment: Initialize which array? I haven't gotten as far as learning how to create a datasource yet.

Comment: Do this. 1. Create a property - NSMutableArray *myArray;  2. Synthesize it.    3. In the ViewDidLoad method copy this. self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; [self.myArray addObject:@"My First Row"];